# gdal not installed - Error in jupyterlab notebook but not in command line

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, gdal

I have been trying to install gdal on jupyter notebook but it is giving error that module not found but from command prompt if I activate the same environment it shows what is expected.

I am using python version 3.7 and windows 10. I installed gdal from conda as well as from jupyter notebook but same error.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current convention to import gdal is

```py
from osgeo import gdal
```

If that doesn't work then you are missing the python bindings for `gdal`. If you have indeed a working `gdal` installation, try to install the python bindings with pip:

```py
pip install gdal==$(gdal-config --version)
```

at which point you should be able to import `gdal` in python.